# Not able to escape apostrophe/special characters in parameterized query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to prevent from having to escape apostrophes and other special characters in my string variables by using a parameterized query with an `OleDbConnection`. I have all of the parameters in the same order, the insert is working, it just does not maintain the characters. I keep getting those pesky html codes. Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to insert into an Access db from a web pages. As I mentioned, its working, just not the special characters.

Here's the code:

```
Dim pConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection pConn = New OleDbConnection(cb.ConnectionString)  
Dim SqlString As String = "INSERT INTO Strings (Mlt_String_ID, Lng_ID, Strg_Name, Sht_Text, Lng_Text, Alt_Text) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"  

Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, pConn)     
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text     
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mlt_String_ID", Mlt_String_ID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lng_ID", Lng_ID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Strg_Name", Strg_Name)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sht_Text", Sht_Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lng_Text", Lng_Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alt_Text", Alt_Text)

    pConn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    pConn.Close()
End Using
```

Updated example: This is directly from the access table after Insert.

```
String_ID String_Name  Long_Text  Short_Text  Alternate_Text Multi_String_ID Lang

993       U_&#176;C_fr &#176;C    &#176;C     &#176;C        651             fr

652       U_°C_jp      °C         °C          °C             651             jp

651       U_°C         °C         °C          °C             651             en
```

jp and en records already existed, the insert of fr record pushes the html codes for the small circle which represents the degree symbol. Happens for all other special characters as well.

Comment: You say you "keep getting those pesky html codes" - what are the errors you are getting? How are you running this VB.NET code? (Since it sounds like there's a website / server involved somewhere if you're getting HTML-related isues.)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the html codes that you are talking about? An example of the results of the insert statement would be helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: Please see updated post.

Comment: What are the values of the variables that you are supplying as the second argument of `AddWithValue`?  I would guess that the HTML encoding is present in those strings, in which case your problem is *not with the sample code* but somewhere earlier in the process.

Comment: In the case of record number 993 the value for Lng_Text, Sht_Text and alt_Text is: °C

Comment: Note that I understand about the redundancy, this is a migration project and the fields will be updated later.

Comment: To help with your wording, those things that look like &#176; are called HTML entities. Maybe set the DataType on these parameters to a Unicode (W) variant of the string type and see if that works?

Comment: Can you show how to do that? I thought this was Unicode8 by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED: The data was being read from a Gridview which had the html encoding. The solution was the following... Dim Sht_Text As String = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(row.Cells.Item(0).Text)